# How to read Folder Associated Information (FAI) through EWS SOAP requests

Tags: soap, exchangewebservices

I have to go and maintain FAI (Folder Associated Information) through EWS SOAP requests.

So I have started experimenting, trying to read them with the CategoryList as an example (so **not** going through the GetUserConfiguration call).

But I'm not succeeding. From what I read left and right, FAIs are stored with the folder, and I can read 'hidden' items using FindItem with Traversal="Associated".
Also, several things are not available in Exchange 2007, so I start with 2010.

I can see that the CategoryList exists with:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:typ="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns:mes="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <typ:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2010"/>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
    <mes:FindItem Traversal="Associated">
      <mes:ItemShape>
        <typ:BaseShape>AllProperties</typ:BaseShape>
      </mes:ItemShape>
      <mes:IndexedPageItemView BasePoint="Beginning" MaxEntriesReturned="100" Offset="0"/>
      <mes:ParentFolderIds>
        <!--typ:DistinguishedFolderId Id="root"/-->
        <!--typ:DistinguishedFolderId Id="inbox"/-->
        <typ:DistinguishedFolderId Id="calendar"/>
      </mes:ParentFolderIds>
    </mes:FindItem>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

(So I'm reading distinguished folder 'calendar' in this example)
This is the response:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <s:Header>
      <h:ServerVersionInfo MajorVersion="15" MinorVersion="0" MajorBuildNumber="1104" MinorBuildNumber="3" Version="V2_22" xmlns:h="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
   </s:Header>
   <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <m:FindItemResponse xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
         <m:ResponseMessages>
            <m:FindItemResponseMessage ResponseClass="Success">
               <m:ResponseCode>NoError</m:ResponseCode>
               <m:RootFolder IndexedPagingOffset="2" TotalItemsInView="2" IncludesLastItemInRange="true">
                  <t:Items>
                     <t:Message>
                        <t:ItemId Id="AQMk [snip] AATj"/>
                        <t:ParentFolderId Id="AQMk [snip] AA=="/>
                        <t:ItemClass>IPM.Configuration.CategoryList</t:ItemClass>
                        <t:Sensitivity>Normal</t:Sensitivity>
                        <t:DateTimeReceived>2015-08-06T14:28:25Z</t:DateTimeReceived>
                        <t:Size>4020</t:Size>
                        <t:Importance>Normal</t:Importance>
                        <t:IsSubmitted>false</t:IsSubmitted>
                        <t:IsDraft>true</t:IsDraft>
                        <t:IsFromMe>false</t:IsFromMe>
                        <t:IsResend>false</t:IsResend>
                        <t:IsUnmodified>false</t:IsUnmodified>
                        <t:DateTimeSent>2015-08-06T14:28:25Z</t:DateTimeSent>
                        <t:DateTimeCreated>2015-08-06T14:28:25Z</t:DateTimeCreated>
                        <t:DisplayCc/>
                        <t:DisplayTo/>
                        <t:HasAttachments>false</t:HasAttachments>
                        <t:Culture>en-US</t:Culture>
                        <t:EffectiveRights>
                           <t:CreateAssociated>false</t:CreateAssociated>
                           <t:CreateContents>false</t:CreateContents>
                           <t:CreateHierarchy>false</t:CreateHierarchy>
                           <t:Delete>true</t:Delete>
                           <t:Modify>true</t:Modify>
                           <t:Read>true</t:Read>
                        </t:EffectiveRights>
                        <t:LastModifiedName>Wendy Bakkertje</t:LastModifiedName>
                        <t:LastModifiedTime>2015-08-06T14:28:25Z</t:LastModifiedTime>
                        <t:IsAssociated>true</t:IsAssociated>
                        <t:ConversationId Id="AAQk [snip] Qn4="/>
                     </t:Message>
                     <t:Message>
                        <t:ItemId Id="AQMk [snip] AATh"/>
                        <t:ParentFolderId Id="AQMk [snip] AA=="/>
                        <t:ItemClass>IPM.Configuration.WorkHours</t:ItemClass>
                        <t:Sensitivity>Normal</t:Sensitivity>
                        <t:DateTimeReceived>2015-08-06T14:28:24Z</t:DateTimeReceived>
                        <t:Size>1879</t:Size>
                        <t:Importance>Normal</t:Importance>
                        <t:IsSubmitted>false</t:IsSubmitted>
                        <t:IsDraft>true</t:IsDraft>
                        <t:IsFromMe>false</t:IsFromMe>
                        <t:IsResend>false</t:IsResend>
                        <t:IsUnmodified>false</t:IsUnmodified>
                        <t:DateTimeSent>2015-08-06T14:28:24Z</t:DateTimeSent>
                        <t:DateTimeCreated>2015-08-06T14:28:24Z</t:DateTimeCreated>
                        <t:DisplayCc/>
                        <t:DisplayTo/>
                        <t:HasAttachments>false</t:HasAttachments>
                        <t:Culture>nl-NL</t:Culture>
                        <t:EffectiveRights>
                           <t:CreateAssociated>false</t:CreateAssociated>
                           <t:CreateContents>false</t:CreateContents>
                           <t:CreateHierarchy>false</t:CreateHierarchy>
                           <t:Delete>true</t:Delete>
                           <t:Modify>true</t:Modify>
                           <t:Read>true</t:Read>
                        </t:EffectiveRights>
                        <t:LastModifiedName>Wendy Bakkertje</t:LastModifiedName>
                        <t:LastModifiedTime>2015-08-06T14:28:24Z</t:LastModifiedTime>
                        <t:IsAssociated>true</t:IsAssociated>
                        <t:ConversationId Id="AAQk [snip] Qn4="/>
                     </t:Message>
                  </t:Items>
               </m:RootFolder>
            </m:FindItemResponseMessage>
         </m:ResponseMessages>
      </m:FindItemResponse>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

But now, how do I get the IPM.Configuration.CategoryList **contents** through this path?

Any hints for the next steps are welcome as well:
- How do I create my own list of FAIs?
- How do I associate my (calendar) items with entries in this list?

Comment: Can you pls share the solution if you found out? Thanks

Comment: @YohanChung I never found a solution and dropped FAIs alltogether

Answer (score -1):

I'm not completely sure this will help, but you may want to review Henning Krauses['] work on the MasterCategoryList to see more about this.  There is a download available at this link, or search MasterCategoryList.

http://www.infinitec.de/post/2011/07/28/Working-with-the-Master-Category-List%E2%80%93EWS-edition.aspx

I worked out a cmdlet based off his work to add categories, but you could just as easy take the code in a different direction.  (Sorry, I can't share that code here.)

Comment: If you're down voting an answer or comment, how about leaving a reason so we can learn your persnickety ways?

Comment: I think somebody downvoted this because it links to Managed API code, where my question is for SOAP calls. Also, since you are not really providing an answer (*I'm not completely sure this will help*), this is more a comment than an answer.

Comment: The downvoter in this case then, is uninformed on EWS.  EWS is Soap over HTTP/S and the Managed API crafts that XML/SOAP on behalf of the client, managing the connections and such.  The ask (as I see it) is "how do I get the categorylist contents..." which is the work of Mr. Kraus.